# window.height and document.height returning the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code, I am trying to implement infinite scroll. The problem am encountering is 'document.height' and 'window.height' are returning me the same value. Can some one help me where I am going wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loadmore.php",
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                            console.log($(document).height());
                            console.log($(window).height());
                        }else{
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

        <style>
        body{ margin:0px; }

        #wrapper{
            width:600px;
            margin:auto;
        }
        .spacer{
            clear:both;
            height:5px;
        }
        .txtarea{
            font-size:18px;
            height:50px;
            width:100%;
        }
        #postswrapper{
            border-bottom:1px dotted #555555;
        }
        .item{
            border-top:1px dotted #555555;
            padding:10px 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .item:hover{
            background:#EFEFEF;
        }
        #newpostlink{
            display:block;text-align:center;border:2px solid #414141;background:#7D7D7D;color:#fff; margin: 0 0 10px;padding:5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>


    </head>

    <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="postswrapper">

        <p style="font-size:28px">Infinite Scroll Demo 2</p>

<div class="item">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
        </div>

        <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center></div>

    </div>

<div id="footer" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;padding:10px;background-color:#FFFFFF">


</div>

    </body>



</html>
```

Comment: loadmore.php by this you get data or not if not then and document is still fit in window without scroll then it same

Comment: this files name is loadmore.php, so basically it is accessing the same file. So how can I calculate the difference to trigger the function?

Comment: using a different file for loading data, still did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe...

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
```